# Windows 8 - recovery drive vs system repair disc

Tags: windows, windows-8, backup, file-recovery

I have created  recovery drive on my usb drive, but haven't created a system repair disc. When I take a backup using Windows 7 File Recovery option, I see a message that says "A Windows system repair disc may be needed to restore this backup.".

What's the difference between the two things?

Answer (score 0):

The system repair disk is used to boot from and restore the system image from the recovery drive. Paul Thurrott at WinSuperSite has a good writeup here of the use for a system repair disk.

[Windows 8 Tip: Use Windows 7 System Image Backup](http://winsupersite.com/windows-8/windows-8-tip-use-windows-7-system-image-backup)

> Note that you’ll probably also want to create a system repair disk,
>   which can be used to boot your PC and restore it using the system
>   image backup you’re now creating, in the event of a hard drive issue
>   or other hardware failure. I wrote about that process in Windows 8
>   Tip: Create Recovery Media. The recovery process has indeed changed in
>   Windows 8, but it’s straightforward and, if anything, nicer than it
>   was in Windows 7 … even if you use system image backups.